# Enable/Disable some textbox controls based on selectedvalue of RadioButtonList in Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

My apologies for bothering you guys again.

The following script works when the RadioButtonList control is inside a Repeater but the Textbox control is outside.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#rblStatus input').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
                    $("#txtOnwerName").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#txtOnwerName").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

However, the problem I am facing right now is that both the RadioButtonList control and the textboxes (about 5 of them) are all inside the Repeater control.

As a result, whether you check the Yes or No value of the RadioButtonList, no textbox is getting disabled or enabled.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Example:

```
 <form ID="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblIssues" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Right">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" />
   </asp:RadioButtonList><br />
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtOnwerName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

Comment: ASP.NET not necessarily assigns same 'id' to a HTML control as defined in ASP.NET code. You should use 'ClientID' property to define HTML 'id' to the element. Please post a webpage source ( Browser > Right Click > View Source) using [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com).

Answer (score 0):

Did yuo check the generated html? If so you would have seen that the ID's of the controls are renamed. So you either need to access them by `ClientID` or by class name.

Start by wrapping each content of an ItemTemplate in a `<div>` for starters. The way it is now it is impossible to discern one Repeater item from another.

```
<div class="repeaterItem">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblIssues" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Right">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOnwerName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Now you can find an item based on the `repeaterItem` class. Check the value and enable/disable the TextBox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.repeaterItem input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
            $(this).closest('div').children('input[type="text"]').prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest('div').children('input[type="text"]').prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
</script>
```